# Метод inflate() в Android

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-layout

Может кто доходчиво объяснить суть параметров метода `inflater.inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)`? С первым вроде понятно, он по сути, преобразуется из XML в полноценный объект. По второму и третьему как то сухо написано, что один - это родительский элемент (не совсем понятно что за родительский элемент), а второй - отвечает за присоединение этого элемента к родителю или что такое.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот отличная статья на англосаксонском: [Understanding Android's LayoutInflater.inflate()](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/understanding-androids-layoutinflater-inflate/)

Краткая выжимка:

1. `LayoutInflater.inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)` - 1 аргумент указание какой файл разметки загрузить. Второй - родительский элемент разметки, в который будет автоматически добавлена загружаемая разметка если 3 параметр `true` или откуда будут взяты `LayoutParams` для загружаемой вьюхи, если `attachToRoot` `false`
2. Из п.1 следует, что следующие строки делают одно и тоже:

```
//загружаем файл разметки и вручную добавляем его в контейнер
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_button, mLinearLayout, false);
mLinearLayout.addView(v);
//загружаем файл разметки и автоматически добавляем его в контейнер
inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_button, mLinearLayout, true);
//загружаем файл разметки и автоматически добавляем его в контейнер
inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_button, mLinearLayout);
```

3. В некоторых случаях система сама добавляет загруженную вьюху в контейнер и ей не надо мешать. Примеры - загрузка разметки для фрагмента и для ячейки списка (`ListView`, `RecyclerView`, `GridView` etc). В этих случаях обязательно надо передавать `false` последним аргументом. Система сама определит в какой момент разметку надо будет добавить в родительский контейнер
4. В некторых случаях нет смысла передавать второй аргумент, т.к. его как бы нет. Это случай кастомной разметки диалогов. В этом случае можно передать `null` вместо родительского элемента загружаемой разметки.
5. В некоторых случаях используется тэг `<merge>` в качестве корневого в файле разметки. Такие вьюхи нельзя поместить в переменную, можно только сразу в разметку. Тут никак не обойтись без передачи `true` в качестве последнего параметра. Такое может пригодится если вы хотите иметь возможность, например, добавлять 2 кнопки, определённые в одном файле разметки в разные контенеры. Например в тот же `LinearLayout` но с разной ориентацией последнего.

Comment: А что из себя представляет контейнер? Здесь вы написали, что это `Layout`, в книге у меня говорится, что это родительская активность. Так что это в итоге?

Comment: @Ivan, контейнером может быть любой наследник `ViewGroup` как и он сам. В книге у вас это или про фрагменты сказано или просто упрощают чтоб не перегружать и не путать. Так-то актвити сама имеет в себе разметку с корневым элементом и в этом смысле её можно назвать контейнером.